# ASP.NET GridView - Editing Dynamic Template Columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemplate

I have created a GridView whose columns are dynamically created based on my data source. I have implemented these columns by using the approach described [here](http://www.developer.com/article.php/10915_3609991_2/Dynamic-Template-Columns-in-the-ASPNET-20-GridView-Control.htm).Those columns display properly on the initial load. However, I need to implement commanding so that a user can edit / delete a row in the GridView.

At this point, I have implemented commanding as I would with a normal GridView. I have a TemplateField with an ItemTemplate that has LinkButton elements for edit and delete. The CommandName for each LinkButton is set to either Edit or Delete respectively.

Oddly, when a user clicks either the Edit or Delete link, the data in the GridView disappears. However, I have verified that I am in fact re-binding the data when one of these LinkButton elements is selected.

Can anyone provide some suggestions as to what the cause could be?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide some sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

Here are good examples. You can figure out postback issue.

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartV20/aspnet/